# Is there any way to modify a Set data structure in iteration (ECMAScript 6)?

Tags: ecmascript-6

The `Set` object in ES6 has a `forEach` method, just like `Array` object does. Is there any way to modify the values when iterating over the `Set` object using the `forEach` method?

For example:

```
// Array object in ES5 can be modified in iteration
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.forEach(function(int, idx, a) {
    a[idx] = int * int;
});
array;  // => [1, 4, 9]
```

But when iterating over a Set object,

```
// Set will not be updated
var set = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
set.forEach(function(val1, val2, s) {
    val2 = val1 * val1;
})
set;   // => [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there any way to achieve the same effect as `Array` object？

Comment: What would happen if you introduce a duplicate when modifying the value?

Comment: Is mutating the original Set necessary? Otherwise you can just map over the Set and make a new one and replace the old one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably do

```
var set = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
set = new Set(Array.from(set, val => val * val));
```

to just make a new set with the new values, and replace the old. Mutating the set as you iterate over it is a bad idea and seems like it's easy to avoid in your usecase.

Comment: Didn't know that `Array.from`, accepts a map function. Cool.

Comment: I'm looking forward to see a `map` function on iterators!

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, an `Iterable.map` is definitely something I'm surprised isn't standard. Easy enough to have in a library at least.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Your answer is elegant. `set = new Set([...set].map(val => val * val));` will achieve the same effect.

Comment: @leslie.zhang Looks like you would be iterating `set` twice with that solution. I would imagine the reason `Array.from` accepts that overload is so it can run the expression at the same time as iterating `set`